# Issue with ELC Image Picker when too many images are selected iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using ELC Image Picker in my project. Here i am getting one issue that is:

when i selected images like 20 picker is working fine but when I select images like 32(selected images count) my app is crashing before dismissal of controller itself and I am getting the error:

> Program received signal:  “0”. Data Formatters temporarily
>   unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading
>   shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

And also I am getting:

> Received memory warning. Level=1

NOTE: when this situation is happened is, first i selected 32 images worked fine and again I selected same number of images it was crashing.

Also I've tried with the example: [github ELCImagePickerController project](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController).

Can any one give me the answer to over come this?

Answer (score 3):

From error you can see that its a memory issue

So you have 2 options

1. set a limit for number of images can be choosed
2. in background save images to temp folder

OR

Customize ELC picker code so that...when a person selects an image... it will take only image path but not image content
and when they are done... now run a loop to get those images into your app.

Comment: thanks for your reply..but from the ELCPickerController i am getting the image path ad ""assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000015&ext=PNG", when i tried to convert this to nsdata i am getting 0 bytes...can you please tell me how to convert this url to image

Comment: you can try like `NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000015&ext=PNG] );`
that may work

Comment: i tried like NSDictionary *dict = [info objectAtIndex:count];   
   //imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
   NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]]] );
   imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; but getting 0 bytes

Answer (score 0):

@SteveGear following code will solve your problem. Just provide the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL and you will get the NSData. Its long time but still, it may help others.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSURL *assetURL = [infoObject objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
__block NSData *assetData;

[assetLibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) // substitute assetURL with your url
 {
     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
     Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc((long)rep.size);
     NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)rep.size error:nil];
     assetData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];//this is NSData what you need.
     //[data writeToFile:assetData atomically:YES]; //Uncomment this if you want to store the data as file.
 }
             failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
 }];
```

Here assetData is what you need.